# Sybase ASE login failed

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

So reading Sybase's utility manual, I found out that I could set up my

localhost server using dsedit.exe..

[image]

And then I tried to register my localhost server in Aqua Data Studios doing the following:

[image]

But then I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What is the admin user name & password for login????

Where/How do I set this up??

According to the documentation, it says the default system admin ID is "sa" with no password..

(http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35888.1501/html/installwin/BHAHDJEE.htm)

I tried to login to Localhost with "sa" but didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: Have you successfully connected using Sybase Central, dbisql, or isql?

Comment: Also, don't tag these as [sql-server] - they are not SQL Server questions.  Use the [Sybase-ase] tag.  And be sure to delete your previous question about adding a server, it helps keep things tidy :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt seem like a login issue. You would get the below error if it was a login/password error.

JZ00L: Login failed. Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).

Can you try the password dba

Also verify what is the correct port number. Is it 2048 or 5000 ? Can you ping in Aqua Data Studio by changing to port 5000 ?

Answer (score 0):

Default port number is 5000, to make sure that try telnet. "o HOST-NAME PORT_NUMBER" is the syntax to test the connection. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was caused by the limited number of connections the developer license allows.

Once that limit is reached, the error `JZ00L: Login failed` is returned when a new connection is tried to be established.